# How can I get a list of tags that have empty description?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

I want help to Stack Overflow by writting description for tags with empty description.

How can I get a list of tags that have empty description?

Comment: It's not guaranteed, but an easy way is to just sort by "New" instead of "Popular" or "Name".  Most new tags don't have an excerpt or a summary.